# How to solve a function subject to a condition R

Tags: r, optimization, portfolio

I'm working on a paper for school.

I have to look for the tangency portfolio using this formula, which I translated in R as follows (basic tangency portfolio formula with matrician algebra.)

```
nom   <- solve(Mat) %*% (ER - RF)

denom <- Ones %*% nom

w    <-  nom %*% solve(denom)
```

This formula gives me also negative weights (short selling), and I would like to add a constraint that only allows weights from 0 to 1, with sum 1.

Who can help me with this?

**Example:**

If I run the code as now, let's say with 3 assets, I will get also negative weights for some assets (ex `c(0.20, -0.40, 0.80)`), with `sum == 1`. (In this case, short selling would be enabled). This is the tangency portfolio that maximizes the sharpe ratio, given the expected return and variance. What I'd love to have is the tangency portfolio without short selling allowed. In the example, I would have the weights something like `c(0.18, 0.05, 0.72)`. It will be incorrect to replace the negative numbers with 0 and also the >1 with 1, as the sum of all the weights should be one

Comment: Adding a small example and desired output will help you get answers faster.

Comment: Example: If I run the code as now, let's say with 3 assets, I will get also negative weights for some assets (ex c(0.20, -0.40, 0.80)), with sum ==1. (In this case, short selling would be enabled).This is the tangency portfolio that maximizes the sharpe ratio, given the expected return and variance. 
What I'd love to have is the tangency portfolio without short selling allowed. in the example, I would have the weights something like c(0.18, 0.05, 0.72).

It will be incorrect to replace the negative numbers with 0 and also the >1 with 1, as the sum of all the weights should be one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as mentioned by @Shree, an example would help understanding more precisely what you're after.

From what I understood, you want `w` to be bounded between [0,1]? From the top of my head you could either shift and scale `w`

```
## Shifting
shift_w <- (w-min(w))
## Scaling
shift_w/max(shift_w)
```

Or, more brutally, replace the values <0 or >1 by a given value or function

```
## What to replace the value with when negative
replace_negative <- 0
## What to replace the value with when superior to 1
replace_one <- 1

## Making sure w is bounded between 0 and 1
ifelse(ifelse(w < 0, replace_negative, w) > 1, replace_one w)
```

Note that `replace_negative` and `replace_one` can also be a function `f(w)` if you want something more complex.

Comment: Example: If I run the code as now, let's say with 3 assets, I will get also negative weights for some assets (ex c(0.20, -0.40, 0.80)), with sum ==1. (In this case, short selling would be enabled).This is the tangency portfolio that maximizes the sharpe ratio, given the expected return and variance. What I'd love to have is the tangency portfolio without short selling allowed. in the example, I would have the weights something like c(0.18, 0.05, 0.72). It will be incorrect to replace the negative numbers with 0 and also the >1 with 1, as the sum of all the weights should be one.